# Leafletjs show a single wrapped map

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to show a single world map and wrap it around so that each area is shown only once on the screen. Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8m13d6vs/

```
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
            noWrap: false,
            attribution: "<a href='http://openstreetmap.org'>OpenStreetMap</a>"
          });

var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1).addLayer(osm);
```

In the above fiddle, wrap is on, but the world map is duplicated. I want a single world map, and on left/right mouse drag, it should wrap around. It should be responsive to the area as well. Is there any way to achieve this? Hope my problem statement is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

There's the Leaflet [`worldCopyJump`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-worldcopyjump) option:

```
var map = L.map('map', {worldCopyJump: true}).setView([0, 0], 1).addLayer(osm);
```

It defaults to `false`, but setting this to `true` will copy the contents of the map over as the user pans beyond the map boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a misunderstanding of the definition of "*wrap*":

In the context of Leaflet's Tile Layer / Grid Layer option [`noWrap`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer-nowrap), it says:

> Whether the layer is wrapped around the antimeridian. If `true`, the GridLayer will only be displayed once at low zoom levels.

So it sounds like simply `noWrap: true` should achieve your objective.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8m13d6vs/3/

BTW you should consider upgrading Leaflet version to 1+

Comment: I believe @sagargurtu wants the map to wrap but as you pan the map to the left or right, they only want one instance of every continent to be displayed.

Comment: @Iavor mm possible, sounds like there is quite a misunderstanding then. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: No problem . I'm trying to see if there is anything in the documentation that would accomplish what sagargurtu is looking for.

Comment: @Iavor: I am not too sure about what OP exactly want to achieve. If the idea is to prevent seeing the same location twice, then you would have to play with map's `maxZoom` and adjust it if the map container size changes. Also set [`worldCopyJump`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-worldcopyjump) map option. There is probably already some posts about it, but feel free to provide your own answer. I will not edit this one, and probably delete it later since it sounds to be off-topic.

Comment: @Iavor is right. In your updated fiddle, when I pan the map right or left, the map is dragged. Instead, I want the map to stay at one place and the content of the map should wrap showing every region only once.